# Take from a list only the element i just clicked and use it

Tags: jquery

i have a list and when someone clicks on an li element then with $.ajax()  i fetch the specific data it wants.

for ie :

```
<li id="test1">test 1 </li>
<li id="test2">test 2 </li>
<li id="test3">test 3 </li>
...
<li id="testN">test N </li>
```

So the ajax part is for test 1 :

```
$('#test1').click(function() {

 $.ajax({
  url: 'fetch.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { temp : 'test1'},
  success: function(data) {
    $('#test1').append(data);
  }    
});
```

and the same for 2,3,4...N

But the problem is it comes too much of code..ok its just copy paste but can i do it another way? meaning when i click test1 element jQuery finds out what element i clicked and runs for it...

Sorry my bad english
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<li class="test" id="test1">test 1 </li>
<li class="test" id="test2">test 2 </li>
<li class="test" id="test3">test 3 </li>
...
<li class="test" id="testN">test N </li>
```

and then

```
$('.test').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
         url: 'fetch.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: { temp : $this.attr('id') },
         success: function(data) {
             $this.append(data);
        }    
    });
});
```

Comment: Without changing the html code you can do selector as $('li[id^="test"]')

Comment: Yes, and as @Vincent Robert mentioned, it might be even nicer to add an id to the `<ul>` or `<ol>` and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a `class="test"` to all your `LI`s and select the class using `$(".test")` or assign a unique ID to the UL `<ul id="tests">` and select only LIs in that UL `$("#tests li")`

Answer (score 1):

Use the change even to only fire when you select an item from the list:

```
$('#test1').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'fetch.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { temp : 'test1'},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#test1').append(data);
    }    
});
```